# Where can I get replacement parts for a Mamiya RB67 film back?

Tags: film, medium-format, mamiya, repair-parts

I bought a film back for my Mamiya RB off eBay over a year ago, and it has this stupid problem where the little piece that holds the top of the film spool (not the takeup reel, and not the piece that presses down, that holds the bottom of the film spool) either broke or came off.

Can I replace that part?

I have been doing some Googling and have not found an answer. Do I just need to buy a new back?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Mamiya? They still make the RB.

Comment: I have seen broken Mamiya backs regularly appearing on different sites including on eBay, large format forum, etc, selling for low prices, for use of parts and pieces. Maybe you can find one of those and reuse that specific part you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not Mamiya still makes the Pro-SD is a bit tentative. Many resources say they stopped in the early 2000's when the RZ67 gained popularity. I believe your best bet would be to buy a cheap broken back and salvage it for parts. RZ and RB backs are not interchangeable and chances are you might need replacement parts down the road anyways. It wouldn't hurt to have a few spares.

Comment: I ended up just replacing it

Answer (score 0):

This part does not seem like it would be the kind of thing that's very replacable, although this is an assumption.

If RB backs are the same as RZ backs then the little bit that holds the film spool in place just needs to be circular so the roll of film can rotate. I would consider trying some modelling putty or a tiny piece of sugru and moulding a small flat circular holder yourself. Alternatively you could find or cut some plastic that's slightly smaller diameter than the circular hole at the top of the medium format spool and glue it on with some polystyrene cement.